# Check-box form validation and submitting the form itself in PHP

Tags: php, html

The following program PHP I've written asks user to select languages they know, and displays the selected languages in the same page itself. I am able to display an error message if the user has not selected any languages. But i need to display the selected check-box items i.e, the lanaguages as a result in the same page itself.
Example: Languages you know are English, French.
Can someone help in this?

```
<?php
$languages_error = $languages_result = $languages_list = "";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if(empty($_POST["languages"])){
        $languages_error = "*Select the languages which you know";
    }
    else
    {
        $languages_result = "Languages selected are";       
    }       
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Check Box Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact">
    <h1>What languages do you know?</h1><br>
    <form action="checkbox.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>      
        <input type="checkbox" name="languages[]" id="languages" value="English"><label for = "gender">English</label></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="languages[]" id="languages" value="Spanish"><label for = "gender">Spanish</label></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="languages[]" id="languages" value="French"><label for = "gender">French</label></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="languages[]" id="languages" value="Germany"><label for = "gender">Germany</label></br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="languages[]" id="languages" value="Chinese"><label for = "gender">Chinese</label></br>     
        <?php echo $languages_error, $languages_result ?></br>      
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset> 
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `echo implode(',', $_POST['languages'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected languages (checkboxes) will be submitted and available as PHP `Array`.

To access these, you can loop through them, and echo as such:

```
$languages_result = $_POST['languages'];

foreach ($languages_result as $language) {
    echo $language . '<br />';
}

// Result is:
// English
// Telegu
// Kanada
```

You can also combine multiple elements within the array, in a `String`, using a delimiter:

```
$languages_result = implode(', ', $_POST['languages']);

echo $languages_result;

// Result is:
// English, Telegu, Kanada
```

Comment: Thanks Jaimil Prajapati! Works fine :)